When I used the 2.4.0 version of the SDK to develop a 1v1 video application, why did an error occur?
When I used the 2.4.0 version of the SDK to develop a 1v1 video application, an error occurred during the development process:

../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/tencent_calls_uikit-2.4.0/lib/src/ui/tuicall_kit_widget.dart:51:12:
Error: The method 'PopScope' isn't defined for the class
'_TUICallKitWidgetState'. ●'_TUICallKitWidgetState' is from
'package:tencent_calls_uikit/src/ui/tuicall_kit_widget.dart'
('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/tencent_calls_uikit-2.4.0/lib/src/ui/tuicall_kit_widget.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
a method named 'PopScope'. return PopScope( ^^^^^^^^ Target
kernel_snapshot failed: ExceptionFAILURE: Build failed with an
exception. flutter-sdk：flutter-3.10.6

How to eliminate this error and make the program run successfully?

PopScope is introduced after flutter version v3.12.0-1.0.pre. As you have flutter version 3.10.* you can update your system flutter version to v3.12.0-1.0.pre or more to utilize PopScope class.
Or,
downgrade tencent_calls_uikit package version to the compatible version. where it uses WillPopScope class.
